# Highlight empty textboxes in form validation using PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html

I am trying to highlight the textboxes that are empty using ONLY php/html. Currently the background of the page changes color not the textbox. My question is how to define the PHP in the html tags

**PHP:**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
                $fname = "<div style='background-color:red'</div>";
            } else {
                $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
            }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "group">
                    <label for="name">First Name</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>
```

Comment: Add a class to your css that does the styling that you want. Then add the class to the html element with your php.

Comment: Styling using only PHP and HTML is not recommended as PHP should only be used in server-side processing while HTML is a markup language. You should really considered using CSS as it is primarily used for presentation semantics.

Answer (score 0):

`$fname = "background-color:red;'";`
Try use `<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" style="<?php $fname;?>">`